# Laravel: cant loads Js file for looping my carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to loop through my images, but my code has a bug that I cant find, I do hope that you could help me outmy
carousel.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });
});
```

I am calling the mycarousel.js file from my home.blade.php

home.blade.php

```
@extends('client.layouts.app')

@section('title')
*** | Home

@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('frontassets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('frontassets/js/myCarousel.js')}}">
    
</script>


@endsection

@section('content')
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
            @foreach($certificates as  $certificate)
        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
            <img src="/storage/CertificateImages/{{$certificate->image}}" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>{{$certificate->title}}</h1>


                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            @endforeach
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a> 
</div>

@endsection
```

The results end up like this, no loop
[image: no loop]

Comment: check in network tab is js files loaded or not

Comment: `.container` is a key page-level layout element in Bootstrap, so including it in a carousel looks suspicious. A quick scan of [the example in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#carousel) confirms that `<div class="container">` is not a standard part of a Bootstrap carousel.

Comment: It's loading, it gives me a 200ok, I have changed to ```<div class="auto-container"> ``` and still no change. Could it be the syntax in mycarousel.js?

Comment: C'mon, make some effort! :-) What debugging have you tried?  Did you try removing that extra `<div>` completely, instead of just renaming the class?  Any JS errors (devtools console)? Are your JS files loading OK (devtools network tab)? Have you checked the rendered HTML?  Have you compared it, *carefully*, to the examples in the docs?  Have you looked at the CSS in devtools to see if there are any obvious class clashes messing with the Bootstrap styles?